# react-charts axes not rendering properly (Hook problem?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react and javascript and trying to render a simple linear chart with react-charts.

The following code generates a chart but fails to render the axes as the `items.map` for `xp` renders an empty array before it gets populated with data, hence it doesn't load properly.

```
export default function CreateChart() {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {
            "_id": "604face09b305032586fe235",
            "username": "Demo",
            "description": "0",
            "duration": 0,
            "date": "2021-03-15T18:52:10.749Z",
            "createdAt": "2021-03-15T18:52:16.684Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-03-15T18:52:16.684Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

    const [xp, setXp] = useState([])


    // GET Exercises
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/exercises")
            .then((result) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setItems(result.data);
                console.log(result.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setError(error);
            })
    }, [])


    // function strip Date
    const stripDate = (date) => {
        const inputDate = new Date(date);
        const noTime = new Date(inputDate.getFullYear(), inputDate.getMonth(), inputDate.getDate());
        const epochTime = noTime.setDate(noTime.getDate())

        return epochTime;
    }

    //  chartdata
    useEffect(() => {
        const minarray = items.map((item) => {
            const container = {};
            container.label = item.username;
            container.data = [[stripDate(item.date), item.duration]]
            return container;
        });
        setXp(minarray);

    }, [items])


    const data = React.useMemo(() =>
        xp,
        [xp]
    );

    const axes = React.useMemo(() =>
        [
            { primary: true, type: 'time', position: 'bottom' },
            { type: 'linear', position: 'left', base: 5 }
        ],
        []
    );



    return (

        // A react-chart hyper-responsively and continuously fills the available
        // space of its parent element automatically

        <Container>
            <Box height={300} width={700}>
                <Chart data={data} axes={axes} tooltip />
            </Box>
        </Container>
    )

}
```

Current output on refresh:
[image]

However if i zoom in/out or change anything related to the chart box in `return()` I get the expected outcome:

[image]

However, as soon as I refresh it goes back to "no axes".

**UPDATE**:
If I place an initial state in items like this:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
        "_id": "604face09b305032586fe235",
        "username": "Demo",
        "description": "0",
        "duration": 0,
        "date": "2021-03-15T18:52:10.749Z",
        "createdAt": "2021-03-15T18:52:16.684Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-15T18:52:16.684Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]);
```

It renders as it should, except that you see the initial data before it loads the current. What I expect is the chart to be empty that if array actually is completely empty and when it contains data it should render properly and not a semi loaded chart as shown above.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, adding a conditional statement before rendering gives the expected outcome.

```
    if (items.length > 0) {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Box height={300} width={700}>
                <Chart data={data} axes={axes} tooltip />
            </Box>
        </Container>
    )
}
return (
    <Container>
        <Box height={300} width={700}>
            <p>No data to put in graph</p>
        </Box>
    </Container>
)
```